# Is it possible to include package contents in List view of Finder?

Tags: mac, browser, finder

When browsing a directory structure in list view, packages and metapackages (`.pkg` and `.mpkg`) remain 'sealed' until you 'Show Package Contents'.

When you do this, a new window is opened. What I would like to do is browse the directory structure, including the contents of packages, in one list view. Possible?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question as it's stated, but the [Suspicious Package](http://www.mothersruin.com/software/SuspiciousPackage/) Quick Look generator gives some useful information about what a package will install and where its files will go.

Note that most (if not all) `.pkg` files contain an `Archive.pax` or `Archive.bom` file which won't give you much information on its own.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that. I'm looking at packages that contain packages that (in some cases) contain packages and I'd like to be able to browse the whole tree. I'm not too fussed about browsing into archives.

Comment: As said, an archive contains Archive.pax or Archive.bom files which cannot be read directly through the Finder.
Using Suspicious Package is a good choice, very effective.

Answer (score 0):

Not with the native Finder, no. The Finder automatically lists the contents of some bundles (like frameworks), but it treats most bundles like a single file and thus does not show the file's contents.